Android Native App Credentials Google Account Login Failed Error: [16] Account reauth failed with type GetCredentialException.TYPE_USER_CANCELED
IDE: Android Studio
Language and framework: kotlin, Jetpack compose
Java version: 11
Gradle sdk info: 
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        compileSdk = 35
Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro

Description: Based on the relevant documentation for Google Android development, I am using the Credential API to integrate Google account login functionality into my Android app. Below is the main code.
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

private val googleIdOption: GetSignInWithGoogleOption by lazy {
    GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(serverClientId =                                                                                                                                                       
context.getString(R.string.google_login_web_client_id))
        .setNonce(generateNonce())
        .build()
}

private val credentialManager by lazy {
    CredentialManager.create(context)
}

fun signInWithGoogle(onSuccess: (String) -> Unit, onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
            .build()

        try {
            val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                request = request,
                context = context
            )
            handleSignIn(result, onSuccess)
        } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
            onError(e)
        } 
    }
}


The UI screen for selecting an account displays correctly, but when I click on an account, an error occurs. The error message is as follows:
androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialCancellationException: [16] Account     
reauth failed.
    at     
androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.convertToJetpackGetException$credentials_release(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:310)
    at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl$onGetCredential$outcome$2.onError(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:172)
    at androidx.credentials.CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl$onGetCredential$outcome$2.onError(CredentialProviderFrameworkImpl.kt:160)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.lambda$onError$2(CredentialManager.java:820)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.$r8$lambda$_rg2Q59c21DJrPoh5aAnwNR78wQ(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at androidx.credentials.CredentialManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.execute(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at android.credentials.CredentialManager$GetCredentialTransport.onError(CredentialManager.java:819)
    at android.credentials.IGetCredentialCallback$Stub.onTransact(IGetCredentialCallback.java:121)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1505)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1444)

and the error type is
GetCredentialException.TYPE_USER_CANCELED

I have searched for many related error solutions on StackOverflow and other websites. Most of the solutions suggest that the web client ID or SHA-1 configuration might be incorrect, but I have repeatedly verified these configurations and tried reconfiguring the web client ID. However, the error still persists. I am currently stuck on this issue. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? If needed, I will provide more related code snippets and Gradle dependencies information.

Try to change GetGoogleIdOptions for GetSignInWithGoogleOption
      val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .setServerClientId(client_id) // replace your client id
                .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
                .setNonce(hashedNonce)
                .build()




            val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                .build()

You should create both web and android client id as well. Try to paste android client id in it rather than web client id.
I have faced the same issue before, usually it will happen when no account signed in the device or emulator. So make sure at least one google account signed in device or emulator, then try after 5 minutes by clicking 1-5 times the sign in button. If it not works then try to check api client id is right or wrong.

Thank you for your response. However, I have configured both the web client ID and the Android client ID, and I have double-checked them. I also tried replacing the web client ID with the Android client ID. The emulator has a valid Google account, but the error still persists.

I have updated the code just try it by using  GetGoogleIdOption.Builder() for credential manager. And provide hashedNonce as well. Hope it will works.

Sorry for the late response, and i will try this later, thanks for your answer again.

I made the code modifications as you mentioned, replaced GetSignInWithGoogleOption with GetGoogleIdOption, no other changes were made, and the following error occurred: "androidx.credentials.exceptions.NoCredentialException: No credentials available"
